# Escape parameters for positional arguments

Tags: bash, gentoo

I have external bash script which is called by system with `bash` to compile golang sources, and I'm able to configure some varialbes. This script is a [golang-build.eclass](https://devmanual.gentoo.org/eclass-reference/golang-build.eclass/index.html). The build function in this script is:

```
golang-build_src_compile() {
    debug-print-function ${FUNCNAME} "$@"

    ego_pn_check
    set -- env GOPATH="${WORKDIR}/${P}:$(get_golibdir_gopath)" \
        GOCACHE="${T}/go-cache" \
        go build -v -work -x ${EGO_BUILD_FLAGS} "${EGO_PN}"
    echo "$@"
    "$@" || die
}
```

The only thing I can configure from outside is `EGO_BUILD_FLAGS` variable.

The problem with this script is when I'm trying to use quotes in `EGO_BUILD_FLAGS` variable, e.g.:

```
EGO_BUILD_FLAGS="-ldflags \"-X main.buildVersion=0\""
```

build script is printing (with `echo`) correct command to execute but actual command fails with error `invalid value "\"-X" for flag -ldflags`. If I just copy printed output and run it manually it completed successfully.

Here is simplified version to reproduce it:

```
EGO_BUILD_FLAGS="-ldflags \"-X main.buildVersion=0\""
set -- go build -x ${EGO_BUILD_FLAGS} github.com/g4s8/gitstrap/cmd/gitstrap
echo "$@"
"$@"
```

the output:

```
go build -x -ldflags "-X main.buildVersion=0" github.com/g4s8/gitstrap/cmd/gitstrap
invalid value "\"-X" for flag -ldflags: missing =<value> in <pattern>=<value>
usage: go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help build' for details.
```

The first line here is working command and looks like expected.
It seems that the problem here is that `$4` is `"-X` and `$5` is `main.buildVersion=0"`.

Is it possible to escape quotes to pass correct build parameters as positional arguments to `set` from script variable?

The only possible solution here is to change `EGO_BUILD_FLAGS` variable, `set -- ...` command is not accessible, it's located in external script file.

Comment: You've encountered the limitation of the unfortunate intersection of a poorly conceived toolchain command-line argument handling (Go-lang) with a short-sighted build system based on the shell language (Gentoo.) Sorry if I sound grumpy, but I've had to deal with both and I don't care for either... My suggestion is that you open a bug report/feature request with Gentoo, asking them to extend their eclass for Golang so that it's actually possible to pass any form of `-ldflags` to Golang builds, since as it stands, this is not really possible. Good luck!

Comment: It looks to me like the only way this could be made to work would be for the eclass to be modified to use `eval` to expand `EGO_BUILD_FLAGS`. I.e., it looks like that behavior was intended but forgotten about.

It is generally considered bad practice, but, for now, you probably will have to simply define `src_compile()` directly in your `.ebuild` instead of calling the eclass-provided function.

Comment: @binki you're right, I found a bug https://bugs.gentoo.org/583238 but it was submitted in 2016 and it's still open.

Answer (score 2):

The quoting is simple, you can just use single quotes instead of double ones:

```
EGO_BUILD_FLAGS='-ldflags "-X main.buildVersion=0"'
```

But that isn't the source of the problem:

```
$ go build -x ${EGO_BUILD_FLAGS} github.com/g4s8/gitstrap/cmd/gitstrap
invalid value "\"-X" for flag -ldflags: missing =<value> in <pattern>=<value>
usage: go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help build' for details.
```

The problem is that you are passing the variable's contents as a single value. See what happens if you run this with `set -x`:

```
$ set -x
$ go build -x ${EGO_BUILD_FLAGS} github.com/g4s8/gitstrap/cmd/gitstrap
+ go build -x -ldflags '"-X' 'main.buildVersion=0"' github.com/g4s8/gitstrap/cmd/gitstrap
invalid value "\"-X" for flag -ldflags: missing =<value> in <pattern>=<value>
usage: go build [-o output] [-i] [build flags] [packages]
Run 'go help build' for details.
```

The simplest solution is to remove the `-ldflags` from your variable and only store the values you want to pass with `-ldflags`. You can then use your variable as you want:

```
EGO_BUILD_FLAGS='-X main.buildVersion=0'
go build -x -ldflags ${EGO_BUILD_FLAGS} github.com/g4s8/gitstrap/cmd/gitstrap
```

If that is not an option, you can use an array instead:

```
EGO_BUILD_FLAGS=('-ldflags' '-X' 'main.buildVersion=0')
go build -x "${EGO_BUILD_FLAGS[@]}" github.com/g4s8/gitstrap/cmd/gitstrap
```

Finally, you could just not quote the values you set in the variable:

```
EGO_BUILD_FLAGS='-ldflags -X main.buildVersion=0'
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but I can't move `-ldflags` from variable, because build function is located in external script file, which I can't modify.

Comment: @g4s8 OK, see updated answer. An array should work for you.

Comment: array is also not a solution for me, because the only thing I can modify is `EGO_BUILD_FLAGS` variable. In array example you changed `go build` command (added `[@]` to `EGO_BUILD_FLAGS`), which I can't access.

Comment: @g4s8 please edit your question and make these limitations clear. We need to know what constraints we are working with so we don't waste your time and ours coming up with approaches that won't work for you. That said, doesn't it work if you just do `EGO_BUILD_FLAGS='-ldflags -X main.buildVersion=0'`? Without quoting?

Comment: sorry if it was not clear, I thought it was enough to say that scrypt is external and called by system. No `"-X main.buildVersion=0"` is a single value for `-ldflags` argument, it can be also rephrased as `-ldflags="-X main.buildVersion=0"`

Comment: @g4s8 I don't have your script, so I can't _really_ test it, but when using `EGO_BUILD_FLAGS='-ldflags -X main.buildVersion=0'`, the command `go build -x ${EGO_BUILD_FLAGS} github.com/g4s8/gitstrap/cmd/gitstrap` only complains about not finding `github.com/g4s8/gitstrap/cmd/gitstrap`, not about the options. Did you try it that way?

Comment: `go build ...` command also works fine for me (it complains because you don't have local copy of package), it's not working **only** with `set -- got get ..` and `"$@"` then

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90166/discussion-between-terdon-and-g4s8).